# AJAX isn't setting a PHP $_POST varibale so it's returning as 'Undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and not so good at PHP. I'm trying to simply send a string saying "Hello" to my PHP page using the JQuery `$.AJAX` function. So far I have successfully got AJAX to send the information to the page and log it in the console but the data doesn't get stored into the POST variable.

Please keep in mind I'm not being lazy by coming to this forum and asking for help but I have no other choice because I've been searching for about 2 days now on how to fix this problem and haven't found anything that's worked.

Here's my HTML (`order.html`) - This isn't all my HTML but it's all you will need):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            <button id="order-btn" type="submit" formaction="PHP/sendMail.php">Order</button>
        </form>
        <!-- JavaScript/JQuery links -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/order.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript (`order.js` - Once again, I'm only providing necessary code)

```
$("#order-btn").click(function() {
    var txt = "Hello!";
    $.ajax({
        url: "PHP/sendMail.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: txt},
        dataType: "html",
        asyc: true,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my PHP(sendMail.PHP - I'm only providing necessary code)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {  
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    echo $data;
} else {
    echo "Failed to grab data.";    
}
```

Just to clarify, in my actual code the URL is the full URL of my website page.

Let me know in the comments if you would like to see the site to get a better understanding of how and why I need this feature to work.

**UPDATE & SOLUTION:**

From the help I received I now understand that AJAX will only update information on the current page (So, for example, if you have an AJAX function on index.html then you can only run AJAX on that page and can't transfer information across pages)

To solve my problem I stopped sending users to the sendMail.php page and instead changed the HTML content of the page I was currently on (order.html) in the $.ajax success method.

Here's the updated JavaScript code:

```
$("#order-btn").click(function() {
                var txt = "Hello!";
                $.ajax({
            url: "order.html",
            type: 'POST',
                data: {data: txt},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
                        if(parseInt(data)!=0) {
                            $("body").html(data);
                        }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
```

I'd like to thank everyone that helped :)

Comment: Is this button #order-btn a form submit button ?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason my HTML has been removed. The order button was within a form using the POST method and the button had a formaction pointing to the sendMail.php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
type: “POST”,
url: “load-page.php”,
data: {page:url}, //with the page number as a parameter
dataType: “html”, //expect html to be returned
success: function(msg){

if(parseInt(msg)!=0) //if no errors
{
    $(‘#pageContent’).html(msg); //load the returned html into 
    pageContet
    $(‘#loading’).css(‘visibility’,’hidden’);//and hide the rotating    
    gif
}
});
```

Like in above example load-page.php is called so data returned is going to dispaly in pageContent which is the id of some div etc and this div is not on load-page.php this div is on the page from where this ajax request is sent.

may be it will make sence
reference link: [Reference Link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)!

Comment: you can edit your previous ans instead of adding new answere.

Comment: I don't quite see what you're getting at here. Would  you mind explaining it in further detail. Also I tried using this code and I just got a bunch of errors. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Just toggled some things with my code and I've managed to get it working. What I've done is change the pages content with the new data rather than taking the user to a completely new page. Thanks for your help man, you've solved my problem. I'll update the code in the original question to hopefully help others who are having this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not like this way as you have called sendMail.php this file and the data returned will be available in the page from where it was called.

Let suppose with button click on page A you called sendMail.php, so the ajax response returned to page A not to sendmAil.php.

Comment: You see that's what I was thinking, as I am new to AJAX I wasn't sure if reloading/changing the page would affect the data because I though AJAX sent it to the server and it would be stored there until used. Would you mind explain to me a way I could send this information to my PHP and store it as a variable? - Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

First thing, garantees that your API is working. Using a toolchain for API, like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/).

If your api is returning what you want, then you go to your javascript code, because I don't see any problem in your code. I even used your code and worked.

Comment: You say my code worked for you. Does this mean PHP also stored data as a variable and displayed it on the page or was it just working in console?

Comment: Just on console. But return from php.

Answer (score -1):

Then use session

```
session_start(); //at the top
$_SESSION['mydata'] = $data; // something like it
```

but as far as I know it's necessary to refresh the page for session to work. please try it

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't work because AJAX isn't sending the data between pages it's only updating/sending information to the current page the function is on. Thanks for your time though :P